# How to determine the correlation if my plot shows two clusters?

Tags: correlation, clustering

Suppose i have a plot like this:
[image]

As shown in the plot, there are two clusters: "no correlation" for the cluster on the left and "strong positive correlation" for the cluster on the right.

Here are some questions:

1. How can i represent the correlation for the data?
2. Say if i can show the correlation as two values (find where the clusters are and then find the correlation for each clusters -- However, i also have some plot looks like this
   [image]

which can't be split into clusters.

How can i interpret the correlation?

Comment: Lets simplify and say that correlation is a function that takes two vectors as inputs and returns the correlation coefficient between them. So, which two vectors you would like to compute the correlation for?

Comment: I think what you are wishing to compute can be obtained by the correlation coefficient of a linear regression line. Fit a linear line to your data (or cluster) and compute the correlation between the predictions and data. This is my best interpretation of what you wrote.